# How to pass a ng-repeat item as a value into Angular Translate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

It is easier to display this than explain it. I am trying to do this...

```
<div ng-repeat="label in itemLists">
   <input id="{{label}}" type="checkbox">
   <label for="{{label}}">{{'food.items.{{label}}' | translate}}</label>
</div>
```

The translate with the {{label}} is the issue.  If I use food.items.cheese it works.

and inside of itemLists is

```
['lettuce', 'cheese', etc...]
```

food items is

```
{
            "lettuce": "Lettuce",
            "cheese": "American Cheese",
            etc...
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have {{}} inside of {{}}.
How about `'food.items.' + label`?